# To find out the regular expression of multi line pattern using python

Tags: python, regex

I have file in which I am trying to match a pattern and replacing that with other string but that matching line is too big and occurs in multi line; and thus my pattern is matching first line and replacing that line only.

Example -

```
m_pMainSceneManager->PushScene<ConfigurationSpecificHelpScreens>(MainScreenPriority::HelpScreens, &m_ContextTable
            , L"HelpScreens.mercury");
```

Here it is in two lines -
till context table`(&m_ContextTable`) is in one line and 
`, L"HelpScreens.mercury");` is in another line.

With so many regular expression I tried this regular expressiona also -

```
cpat = re.compile(r'.*m_pMainSceneManager->PushScene<ConfigurationSpecificHelpScreens>\(.*\n.*\)')
```

I tried above with `re.MULTILINE` and without that also. But no luck.

Comment: re.compile(r'.*m_pMainSceneManager->PushScene\(.*\n.*\)')

Comment: re.compile(r'.*m_pMainSceneManager->PushScene\(.*\n.*\)')  This is the expression which is not working

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you should use `flags=re.DOTALL`. Read more about `re.compile` here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html . `re.DOTALL` means searching including newlines.

```
>>> import re  
>>> print(re.match('.', '\n'))
None
>>> print(re.match('.', '\n', flags=re.DOTALL))
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02B848E0>
```

In your particular case you can use this:

```
>>> s = '''m_pMainSceneManager->PushScene<ConfigurationSpecificHelpScreens>(MainScreenPriority::HelpScreens, &m_ContextTable
...             , L"HelpScreens.mercury");'''
>>> s
'm_pMainSceneManager->PushScene<ConfigurationSpecificHelpScreens>(MainScreenPriority::HelpScreens, &m_ContextTable\n            ,  L"HelpScreens.mercury");'
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'm_pMainSceneManager->PushScene<ConfigurationSpecificHelpScreens>\(.*?\)', flags=re.DOTALL)
>>> pattern.match(s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02DE2AA0>
```

Comment: THanks for your response. But I did try with re.DOTALL but no luck. I am looking for the exact regex. Please help. If you need more info please let me know

Comment: @user2564083 I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks you very much Daronna. That is workin now. Highly appreciated ! Merry Christmas :)